# Failed to use .dll library because of outdated F# compiler in VS2017

Tags: .net, f#, visual-studio-2017, metadata, visual-studio-2019

**Anonymous records in newer version**
I have two versions of a private library: `Proxy.1.1.5.dll` and `Proxy.2.0.0.dll`.
Newer uses F# anonymous records. Other differences are not so important (I guess).

**Equal `VS2019` build config**
Both versions are built and published to private `NuGet` feed by a `GitHub` hosted server with `Visual Studio 2019` installed, based on the same script, so the initial conditions are equal. No warnings.

---

**F# compiler version error on `VS2017`**
The `Models` project uses `Proxy.1.1.5` package (plain .dll, no sources). It builds perfectly by `Visual Studio 2017` on my local machine. However, with `Proxy.2.0.0` it fails to compile due to:

```
error FS0229: Error opening binary file 
    'C:\Projects\Dashboard.WPF\packages\Proxy.2.0.0\lib\net462\Proxy.dll':
    Error reading/writing metadata for the F# compiled DLL 
      'C:\Projects\Dashboard.WPF\packages\Proxy.2.0.0\lib\net462\Proxy.dll'.
    Was the DLL compiled with an earlier version of the F# compiler? (
        error: 'lookup_uniq in table istrings out of range, n = 110, sizeof(tab) = 6').
```

Obviously, not *earlier* but *newer* version actually

---

**Expected behavior**
`F#` version in my `Visual Studio 2017` does not support anonymous records.
But I expected that any .dll can be used as a dependency to compile `Models` project in outdated `VS2017`, just because it's `.dll` and not `.fs` sources to compile them too. The .dll contains plain `IL` code and anonymous records are replaced by compiler-generated classes during a compilation (so before the .dll is created).

**Questions**

1. How is that possible?
2. Did it really choose a `F#` compiler version based just on code itself despite equal environment conditions in both cases?
3. How can I build the dependent project `Models` with `Proxy.2.0.0.dll` version without installing `Visual Studio 2019` on my local machine?
   3.1. Can `fsc.exe --nointerfacedata` help?

   > Instructs the compiler to omit the resource it normally adds to an assembly that includes F#-specific metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to use such a `.dll` from an older compiler that doesn't understand Anonymous Records. This is because the feature added to the F# metadata format, which has an unfortunate consequence of breaking forwards-compatibility whenever that new (relative to the old compiler) metadata is written to the metadata blob by using the feature. From a support standpoint, forwards-compatibility is preferred but not guaranteed.

This is what is supported:

- Newer compiler can consume a binary produced by older compiler
- Newer compiler can depend on older FSharp.Core
- Newer compiler can re-bind with older FSharp.Core without recompiling
- Older compiler can depend on newer FSharp.Core
- Older compiler can re-bind with newer FSharp.Core without recompiling

This is what will often work, but is not guaranteed to work:

- Older compiler can consume binary produced by newer compiler
- Older compiler can consume *all* constructs in newer FSharp.Core

**Note:** This assumes F# post-.NET Framework 3.5. There are special considerations for using F# with old versions of the .NET Framework.

The reason why these last two points aren't guaranteed to work is that there may be a new concept that is fundamentally impossible for an older compiler to understand. One such example would be the `voidptr` type in FSharp.Core 4.5.2 or higher. This is a new primitive that an older compiler cannot possibly interpret correctly.

Unfortunately, this gets confusing whenever the use of a feature involves writing to the metadata format in a way that an older compiler cannot understand. The compiler error should probably be improved.

Answer (score 1):

1. F# analyzes dlls for F#-related metadata in order to give special treatment to F# objects. You should be able to use these dlls from C# just fine. But the old F# compiler can't understand the metadata produced from the new F# compiler.
2. [Don't understand question.]
3. Why would you want to use VS2017 now? It's possible that removing metadata may enables VS2017 builds but you will not be able to compile dependent projects in the same way as features that require F# to F# understanding will then not work betweeen projects.

Comment: Silly reason for VS2017: constantly no time to clean up free space, transfer all settings, extensions, ReSharper, etc.